# Invalid redirect to action in another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a razor view with the path `~/Views/ReservationDetails/AddMeals.cshtml` which is rendered by the controller `ReservationDetails`. In the View I use the following Html helper action link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Wróć", (ViewBag.ReservationId!=0?"Edit":"Create"),"ClientReservations",new { id=ViewBag.ReservationId})
```

When I edit MealsReservations and I want to come back to `Edit` it redirects me to ReservationDetails/Edit/Length=18?

However when I add meals for reservation for the first time and I want to come back, then it redirects me properly to `Create` in controller ClientReservations.

What can it be the reason?

Comment: Because you need a 5th `null` parameter (for the `htmlAttributes`) - `@Html.ActionLink("Wróć", ....new { id=ViewBag.ReservationId}, null)`

Comment: You're using `ActionLink` with 4 [arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx): @Html.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, routeValues, htmlAttributes). To use 5 arguments just add `null` at the last argument place.